# different sku for all products for recognizing the location in store

Tags: magento, location, skus

we have some 2000 products stored in warehouse.

now we have to give the every product "location id" so that if customer ordered online,

we can search the "location id" by product and than we can deliver to customer.

how to put location id for each product in a site.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can add Location id as a product attribute. Export the product csv fill the appropriate location ids of the product then import back. I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create custom attribute for product as "location", In admin panel go to

```
Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes
```

Create your own attribute for each product and while creating product store the location [location id] etc.

For more information to create custom attribute for product check out this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields

and you need to add this custome attribute to quote and order also check this http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

Thanks